# "No value for search_text was available on the provided input" while working on chatbot

Tags: python-3.x, input, chatbot

So I have run the code and fortunately it worked and a user interface popped up of chatbot but it is not giving me the answer of my particular question and "No value for search_text was available on the provided input" is shown everytime i search anything other than "hello". How to resolve and get exact responses as question. I ran the code for chatbot and it worked as i got GUI , I expected it to generate responses of my questions but the chatbot is not giving answers to the questions instead generating random responses hence giving this "No value for search_text was available on the provided input"`your text`